# Interactive Broker - No Security Definition has been found for the request

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

I am trying to get historical data of a specific stock from IBKR, but it seems like the testApp() function here is not being called or something. I'm able to connect to the TWS station, but somehow I'm not being fed back data, so was wondering if there is anything wrong with my Wrapper function?

Also, When I run the code, I get back this error message: "No Security Definition has been found for the request".

Any suggestions as to how I can go about fixing this?

```
class TestClient(EClient):
    def __init__(self, wrapper):
        EClient.__init__(self, wrapper)


class TestWrapper(wrapper.EWrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        wrapper.EWrapper.__init__(self)


class TestApp(TestWrapper, TestClient):
    def __init__(self):
        TestWrapper.__init__(self)
        TestClient.__init__(self, wrapper=self)

    def error(self, reqid, errorcode, errorstring):
        print("Error: ", reqid, " ", errorcode, " ", errorstring)

    def historicalData(self, reqid: int, bar: BarData):
        print("HistoricalData. ReqId:", reqid, "BarData.", bar)

    def historicalDataUpdate(self, reqid: int, bar: BarData):
        print("HistoricalDataUpdate. ReqId:", reqid, "BarData.", bar)

    def historicalDataEnd(self, reqid: int, start: str, end: str):
        print("HistoricalDataEnd. ReqId:", reqid, "from", start, "to", end)
        app.disconnect()
        print("Finished")

    def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
        super().nextValidId(orderId)

        logging.debug("setting nextValidOrderId: %d", orderId)
        self.nextValidOrderId = orderId
        print("NextValidId:", orderId)

    def contractDetails(self, reqId: int, contractDetails: ContractDetails):
        super().contractDetails(reqId, contractDetails)
        printinstance(contractDetails)
        self.reqContractDetails(10004, ContractSamples.NewsFeedForQuery())

    def contractDetailsEnd(self, reqId: int):
        super().contractDetailsEnd(reqId)
        print("ContractDetailsEnd. ReqId:", reqId)


def main():
    app = TestApp()
    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=1)
    print(app.isConnected())
    time.sleep(1)

    contract = Contract()

    contract.secType = "STK"
    contract.symbol = "AAPL"
    contract.currency = "USD"
    contract.exchange = "NASDAQ"


    querytime = (datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=180)).strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")

    app.reqHistoricalData(4001, contract, querytime, "1 M", "1 day", "MIDPOINT", 1, 1, False, [])

    app.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It seems that the error you're getting answers your question as to why you aren't getting back any data.  I assume you're not getting back data because you have not communicated a valid Security for which to return data.  I assume that your problem is that the `Contract` object you build does not correctly define the request you are making for data.  I don't know the particular API.  Maybe someone will see this who knows the API.  All I can offer is that you review the docs and examples, and try to figure out why the content of your request leads to that error.

Answer (score 0):

The exchange should be SMART for smart routing to all available exchanges.  If you really want to just use NASDAQ then the exchange should be ISLAND I think.  I know it works because I tested it but haven't ever used it in real trading for things like rebates.  I also have no idea whether it would give historical data for just the one exchange but I seriously doubt it.

You have the contractDetails implemented so you could always call that first then you can trade AAPL by specifying just `contract.conId = 265598`